# Print variable which contains single and dimensional quote, as input element value

Tags: php, html

I have `$variable` which contains single and dimensional quotes, like this `a's"d`

I want write this variable as value of checkbox element

```
<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>" />
```

but when I see result after send html forms, value from checkbox is not correct (reason is quotes), what is right way, for write variables like this, as input value?

Comment: uhm addslashes http://php.net/manual/de/function.addslashes.php ?

Comment: addslashes will cause more problems by adding a slash. You need to use `htmlentities`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES`

```
<?php echo(htmlentities($variable, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401)); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can escape the dimensional quotes :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="<?php echo str_replace('"','\\"',$variable); ?>" />
```

Or you can use `htmlspecialchars()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 3):

You want to encode your charachters to html elements so they do not break the string. Try something like this

```
$variable = htmlentities($variable);
<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="<?php echo $variable; ?>" />
```

The spec is written here http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php if you need more info